# Amplify storage nosql - How to edit a table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I have a react web web, and I just config amplify and added the storage nosql option.

I created a table and the columns, but now I want to add another column, how can I edit that Table? I couldn't find any reference [here on the docs](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/storage)

Command used to config amplify storage:

`amplify add storage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it out:

```
amplify storage remove <storageName>
```

Also, if you run `amplify anything` it'll display all commands and a little description for each one.